# Remove primary key and auto-increment in database using migration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have table with primary key and auto-increment field, I want make new migration to drop primary key index and also remove the auto increment field. How can i achieve this.

I created new migration as

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tbl_message_read_state', function (Blueprint $table) {

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('tbl_message_read_state', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->dropPrimary('message_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('message_id');
    });
}
```

It gave me error in command as `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]

  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'message _id' (SQL: alter table tbl_'message_read_state' add 'message_id' int unsigned not null)`

Whats Wrong ?????

Answer (score 11):

Blueprint class offers dropPrimary methods that allow you to remove primary key.

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropPrimary();
        $table->unsignedInteger('id'); // for removing auto increment

    });
}
```

Comment: What wil be the artisan command sir ? as i think it will be `php artisan make:migration drop_primary_from_tablename --table=tablename` Is this right?

Comment: It seems that providing a `change` method to the chain is necessary. Otherwise we will encounter the error `Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'`.

Answer (score 5):

This did it for me:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Make AI field `id` unsigned otherwise SQL 
    // will throw error when you try to remove it
    $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->change();

    $table->dropColumn('id');

    // If there was a foreign on message_id, make sure to remove it
    $table->dropForeign('table_name_message_id_foreign');

    $table->dropPrimary('message_id');
    $table->dropColumn('message_id');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `dropPrimary` method only removed the primary key, not the column. You would have to do:

```
    /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('tbl_message_read_state', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->dropPrimary('message_id');
        $table->dropColumn('message_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('message_id');
    });
}
```

Or instead of dropping and re-creating the column, you can use `change` in Laravel 5.

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('tbl_message_read_state', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->dropPrimary('message_id');
        $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned()->change();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$table->dropPrimary('id_primary');
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the primary key:

```
$table->dropPrimary( 'id' );
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#dropping-indexes)

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple drop column

`$table->dropColumn('id');`

Answer (score -5):

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#dropping-indexes

1. tabel_name
2. column
3. `index $table->dropPrimary('users_id_primary');`