# How to change primary key in laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to change the primary key on a table so I can use an other column as foreign key too.

Here's the migration for the creation

```php
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('blacklists', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('adv_id')->default(0);
        // ...other columns
   });
}
```

Then, I've made an other migration to change the **adv_id** column type in order to prepare the addition of a foreign key

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('blacklists', function(Blueprint $table){
         $table->integer('adv_id')->unsigned()->change();
    });
}
```

Here's where I'm stocked

```php
public function up()
{
     Schema::table('blacklists', function(Blueprint $table) {
         $table->dropPrimary('id');
         $table->integer('adv_id')->primary()->change();
     });
}
```

When I run the last migration, I got this error message

```sql
Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: alter table `blacklists` drop primary key)
```

Comment: I think `dropPrimary` drops the index, not necessarily the column... see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47270330/886824 and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#dropping-columns

Comment: but do I need to drop the column if I just want to use an other column as the index ?

Comment: The problem is that MySQL/MariaDB only allows `AUTOINCREMENT` on the `PRIMARY` - so you don't necessarily need to get rid of the column but you do need to get rid of the auto-increment.

Comment: ok ! thanks for the tip ! that solved it ! 
If you can post it as the answer, i'll validate it

Answer (score 2):

this work for me

```
public function up()
{
 Schema::table('blacklists', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->dropPrimary();
   $table->unsignedInteger('id')->change();
   $table->dropColumn('id');
   $table->uuid()->primary()->unique()->index()->first();
 });
```

Comment: This produced an error for me: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @gboone did you get annay solution ?

Comment: @gboone if not i advise you to separate it into 2 migrations: one for dropping the primary key and the other one for setting the new primary key

Answer (score 0):

You can try this because at a time only one auto-increment allow.

```
public function up()
{
 Schema::table('blacklists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary('id');
    $table->integer('adv_id')->unsigned()->change();
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I am showing multiple Schema blocks in the one migration, and am answering the question in general of how to change the primary key in laravel. For example, make a uuid field the primary:

```
use Iluminate\Support\Str;
use App\Blacklists;

public function up()
{
  Schema::table('blacklists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('uuid')->first();
  });

  $blacklists = Blacklists::all();
  if($blacklists) {
    foreach($blacklists as $blacklist) {
      $blacklist->uuid = Str::uuid();
      $blacklist->update();
    }
  }

  Schema::table('blacklists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary();
    $table->unsignedInteger('id')->change();
    $table->dropColumn('id');
  });

  Schema::table('blacklists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->primary('uuid');
    $table->renameColumn('uuid', 'id');
  });

}
```